# Convert JSON to GeoJSON

Tags: php, json, cakephp, geojson

Is there any function or library available in PHP to convert Json object into Geojson object?

Answer (score 10):

[GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#introduction) is just JSON containing a certain structure. So if your objects have this structure, they "are GeoJSON".

See http://wiki.geojson.org/Users for libraries which can build GeoJSON objects.

Answer (score 5):

JSON is just javascript object notation - it can describe anything. GeoJSON is a subset of this for describing spatial data

Answer (score -5):

PHP routines that can convert your SQL Query to GeoJSON. Table attributes are converted into JSON at the same time.

These are the PHP routines:

PHP PostGIS to GeoJSON.

PHP SQLite3 to GeoJSON.

PHP Spatialite to GeoJSON.

You can get them my gist.
https://gist.github.com/ns-1m

Comment: Totally not relevant to the question

Comment: It is not dead the gist. Just google it e.g. "PHP Spatialite to GeoJSON"